# Handle Dom using Webpack

Tags: javascript, dom, webpack, frontend, webpack-dev-server

How do I manipulate the DOM using Webpack and pure Javascript?

I'm having the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: register is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

My index.js has only:

```
function register() {
    alert('Hello')
}
```

---

My test scenario:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="matri">Matri</label>
    <input class="form-control col-12" type="text" placeholder="Enter your matri" id="matry">
</div>

<div class="text-left mt-5" style="width: 100%;">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="register()" type="button">Register</button>
</div>
```

I would like to work using a scope similar to the MVC principle.
Where I have a model and my control to manipulate DOM.
Is there such a possibility or is there a better alternative?

My organization structure is below the image:

[image: My structure]

my Webpack.config.js file

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',

                options: {
                    presets: ['env']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,

                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',

                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',

                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'app.min.css', path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') })
    ],

    entry: './src/index.js',

    output: {
        filename: './dist/bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    mode: 'production'
};
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. But if you literally mean just working with DOM, then you should simply write all Web API calls right in the js code, e.g. index.js. For example, `document.querySelector('body')`, etc.

Comment: I would like to call a function within index. JS, for example. But it generates an error that I put in the beginning of my posting. I made an issue!

Comment: Where did you define your register function? And insert the part of the code where cadastra is used. Please, be specific. Your error exactly depends on the context, so provide it instead of forcing us asking you endless questions, with all respect.